# Multiple layouts over google maps

Tags: nativescript

i was wondering is it possible to create something like this? https://prnt.sc/o3b62o google map on full screen and 2 buttons. (one top and one at the bottom) I have version with grid layout, but then map is not interactive.

```
<GridLayout className="map-layout" rows="*, auto">
    <StackLayout className="map" rowSpan="2">
        <MapView width="100%"height="100%":zoom="7"
            :latitude="parseFloat(location.lat)"
            :longitude="parseFloat(location.lng)"/>
    </StackLayout>

    <Button text="bottom button" row="1"></Button>
    <Button text="top button" row="0"></Button>
</GridLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for a floating space at top and bottom of map, you are not suppose to use two rows, it should be one row with vertical alignment set to top / bottom.

```
<GridLayout class="map-layout">
    <MapView class="map" :zoom="7"
            :latitude="parseFloat(location.lat)"
            :longitude="parseFloat(location.lng)"/>
    <Button text="bottom button" verticalAlignment="bottom"></Button>
    <Button text="top button" verticalAlignment="top"></Button>
</GridLayout>
```

Lear more about layouts at https://www.nslayouts.com/

Comment: I just tested on android and with this layout i get error. 'Calling js method onCreateView failed'. On ios works fine.

Comment: If you just place another button / label instead of MapView does it still crash? I hope not, so it must be something with MapView alone, the layout is still correct. You might have to debug step by step and see where exactly it crashes.

Comment: Yeap, it looks like there is problem with mapView. Removing mapView and using button instead app doesnt crash anymore.

Comment: You must wait for map ready event incase if you are doing any manipulation on MapView, that could also be an reason for crash.

Comment: Is there another layout version that i could use? Even displaying buttons after map init app crashes.

Comment: Using without buttons app still crashes. So there is problem with mapView in gridLayout.

Comment: I have MapView with GridLayout and never had an issue. Do you have a sample project?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195138/discussion-between-wizard-and-manoj).

Comment: I just saw your full page code, it's not same as I have above. The extra StackLayout and GridLayout wrapping map is not required. Hope you figured it out.